# WPF button in datagrid binding path window.resource

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid, path

Hi I have a datagrid in WPF.  The Column is a button, binds to a int value.  I'd like to have the button content path to bind to the window.resource path, e.g. when the value is 0, the button content show the path RightArrow and when the value is 1, it shows the LeftArrow.  How do I do that?  Do I have to use a IvalueConverter to do this?  The following are my xaml code.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Path x:Key="RightArrow" Data="M4,15V9H12V4.16L19.84,12L12,19.84V15H4Z" Fill="Black" />
    <Path x:Key="LeftArrow" Data="M20,10V14H11L14.5,17.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L14.5,6.5L11,10H20Z" Fill="Black" />
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid Name="SomeDtg" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Interchangeble?" Width = "2*">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Button>
                    .......
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is a control. Don't create controls as resources; they can only have one parent at a time. You didn't give the name of the property the column binds to, so I called it `EvenOddProperty`.

Another way to do this would be to create two DataTemplates which display left or right arrows, and swap those in with the trigger. That's how you create a control as a resource: Put it in a DataTemplate that's a resource. New instances of the DataTemplate contents are created each time it's applied.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="RightArrow">M4,15V9H12V4.16L19.84,12L12,19.84V15H4Z</PathGeometry>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="LeftArrow">M20,10V14H11L14.5,17.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L14.5,6.5L11,10H20Z</PathGeometry>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button>
            <Path
                Fill="Black"
                >
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EvenOddProperty}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource RightArrow}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EvenOddProperty}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource LeftArrow}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```